# Can the password in HTTP Basic be optional?

Tags: http, soa, basic-authentication

I'd like to use HTTP Basic auth to do password-less authentication between trusted services in a private network. Is it acceptable to leave out the password field entirely when using Basic auth? Is there a better authentication mechanism I should research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP Basic auth, the username and password are concatenated using a colon then encoded in base64 and the resulting header looks something like:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

The Basic part specified basic authentication and the second part is the base64 encoded token. It doesn't have to be a username/password combo, but can just be a username with a blank password, or a username alone. You just have to be aware of that when decoding the authorization header.

Comment: I figured I could get away with it, but is it standards compliant?

Comment: Yes because the authentication header value consists of scheme and parameter. Scheme is Basic in this case, parameter is the base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2617 defines them as

```
user-pass   = userid ":" password
userid      = *<TEXT excluding ":">
password    = *TEXT
```

and `*` in the ABNF means "0 or more."

Meaning the `userid` and `password` can be empty, in which case `:` is encoded into Base64.

Comment: fyi - RFC 7617 obsoletes RFC 2617 since 2015. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617

Comment: @Michael I knew it. However, RFC 7617 doesn’t contain the ABNF expressions for the `userid` and `password`, not clarifying whether it can be empty. It poorly defines `userid` and `password` compared to the previous specification.